# Differentiating between runs that start at different timestamps

Tags: python, time-series, dataset, predictive-modeling

I have a CSV file of the latitude and longitude coordinates of trains in the format `[timestamp, runID, latitude, longitude]`.
The problem is that I have tracked multiple trains over the course of a few days, and once a train is done running it will then get a new runID for the next service it runs, meaning that some runs will start at a timestamp other than 0, and a different location.

How should I represent this data, and what predictive models would best suit such a dataset?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You told us the 1st field was `timestamp`, which I take to be an ISO-8601 UTC instant in time, often represented as seconds since midnight 1970-01-01Z. You said that "some runs will start at a timestamp other than `0`" -- are we to understand that most trains started their run at midnight 1970-01-01Z ?!?

Comment: No, the timestamp is seconds since the recording started.

Comment: Ok, that sounds more plausible. But I'm still astonished. You have a large number of train runs which all started at timestamp `0`, so for example they all simultaneously left their various rail stations at noon UTC on 2024-02-07 ?!? That still makes little sense. The various (lat, long)'s are universally interpretable. But the timestamps sound like they are not.  Begin by making them proper ISO-8601 UTC timestamps. Then you can worry about relative  time [offsets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) or crow-flies-distance position offsets for a given train.

Comment: Adding a sample dataset might be beneficial for us.